# How to use DensityPlot in polar cordinate for a range of raduises

Tags: plotting

I want to show values of a function $f[r,t]$ using DensityPlot but I don't know how to show the function only fo $r>1$. Could somebody please help me? I have written the below code, but I don't know how to make it work only for $r>1$.

```
Rc = 0.1;
f[r_, t_] := 
  Exp[-Sum[(-16 (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(
         2 + 4 mz) - 
        8 (-1)^mz (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(
         1 + 2 mz) (Sin[(3 + 2 mz) t] - 
           Sin[t - 
             2 mz t]))/((-1 + (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - 
               r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(2 + 4 mz)) (1 + 
          2 mz) \[Pi]), {mz, 0, 10}]];
DensityPlot[
 f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5], 
 PlotPoints -> 200, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {0, 1}, All}]
```

Comment: When I evaluate your code I get "General::munfl Exp[-938.837] is too small" messages which means that the function needs to be rescaled. I think this also explains why the plot has only two colors.

Comment: How can I rescale it?@Lotus

Comment: Try to plot without `Exp`, you will see more interesting picture and also `PlotLegend` shows very big negative values for `Sum`, that explains message "Exp[...] is too small".

Comment: I agree that it's better but still, most of the plane is blue @Alx

Comment: I think the problem is I can't make exclusion work @Alx because if I can, the very very large values disappear.

Comment: You could use NMinimize and NMaximize on the function to find the min and max values and divide the function by them to see how the plot rescales. For more intelligent rescaling one would have to know details such as what these represent etc..

Comment: Also, it is generally true that a few terms of the function could be dominating the others. Try removing those terms and plot the rest. Just a thought.

Comment: But I need all the terms! @Lotus

Comment: Well if one term gives rise to Exp[1000] then the rest of the terms don't matter at all !!

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `RegionDifference` instead of `Exclusions->Disk[...]`, this also solves the problem of small exponents: they appear near to `{0,0}` and `RegionDifference` does exclude this region.

```
Rc = 0.1;
f[r_, t_] := 
  Exp[-Sum[(-16 (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - 
               r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(2 + 4 mz) - 
        8 (-1)^mz (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - 
               r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(1 + 
            2 mz) (Sin[(3 + 2 mz) t] - 
           Sin[t - 2 mz t]))/((-1 + (((r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - 
                r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)))^(2 + 4 mz)) (1 + 
          2 mz) π), {mz, 0, 10}]];
DensityPlot[
 f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ 
  Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, All}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Or using `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ 
  Region[RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1.5], Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8]]], 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, All}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]